# sql query to check which of my friends table has a post for me

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a query to find which of my friends has posts for me to show it on my post feed. Here is what i have: 1. A table where i save my friends 2. A table where i save my posts. Example:

```
TABLE FRIENDS

ID   USER   FRIEND
1     me     chris
2     me     george
3     me     john
```

etc.

```
TABLE POSTS

ID   MESSAGE   USER      DATETIME
1    lala       john      2013-15-03 17:27:01
2    lala       george    2013-15-02 17:02:01
3    lala1      george    2013-16-03 13:28:01
4    lala1      john      2013-21-05 19:27:01
5    lala2      john      2013-30-08 17:27:01
```

etc...
I have more than 200 rows in this table

So the feed should result as follows:

```
5    lala2      john      2013-30-08 17:27:01
4    lala1      john      2013-21-05 19:27:01
3    lala1      george    2013-16-03 13:28:01
1    lala       john      2013-15-03 17:27:01
2    lala       george    2013-15-02 17:02:01
```

What the query should look like?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does each user have its own table in database?

Comment: each user does not have its own table in database

Comment: I think the title is a bit ambiguous then

Comment: I just wrote it like this because the table is called FRIENDS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually this is wrong design, you need a user table with id per user and a friends table that contains only ids, but in this case this is what you can do:

first, add a foreign key to the posts table,

so you can know which message is for who, so it would look like this:

```
TABLE POSTS

ID   MESSAGE   USER       TO      DATETIME
1    lala       john      me    2013-15-03 17:27:01
2    lala       george    me    2013-15-02 17:02:01
3    lala1      george    me    2013-16-03 13:28:01
4    lala1      john      me    2013-21-05 19:27:01
5    lala2      john      me    2013-30-08 17:27:01
```

then the query will be:

```
select * from friends f join posts p on f.user=p.to
```